# Error on trying to connect to MSOL service with PHP and Powershell

Tags: php, powershell, office365

I'm trying to connect to Msol Service with powershell

```
$username = "username@domain.com"
$password = "password"

$secure_password = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credencial = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $secure_password)

Import-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService -Credential $credencial

Get-MSolGroup -GroupType DistributionList -SearchString "groupname" | Select DisplayName, EmailAddress, ObjectId | Out-String
```

And PHP:

```
$command = 'powershell -File "'.dirname(__DIR__).'\\ps\\run.ps1"';
exec($command, $output);
print_r($output);
```

From local PC powershell script runs without any errors, but with PHP it throws an error:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Exception of type 'Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineEx
    [1] => ception' was thrown.
    [2] =>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mic
    [3] =>    rosoftOnlineException
    [4] =>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x80090345,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Autom
    [5] =>    ation.ConnectMsolService
    [6] =>     + PSComputerName        : s021
    [7] => 
    [8] => You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.
    [9] =>     + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [Get-MsolGroup], Microsoft
    [10] =>    OnlineException
    [11] =>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.Micro
    [12] =>    softOnlineException,Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.GetGroup
    [13] =>     + PSComputerName        : s021
    [14] => 
    [15] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the exception suggests: You must call the Connect-MsolService cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets.

Comment: But in powershell script exists command Connect-MsolService. This exception is thrown by another command "Get-MsolGroup".

"Connect-MsolService" only throws unknown exception without any details what is wrong: Exception of type Microsoft.Online.Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown.

Comment: @VaidasV are these two command executed in the same powershell session?

Comment: These commands are executed in same powershell script, so I think that in same session.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, storing a password in a script in plain text is a terrible idea. If your goal is to provide a web interface to certain operations in Azure Active Directory, your best bet is to use the [Azure Active Directory Graph API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx), which was designed for this. If you still feel you have a valid scenario for this, you have analyzed and weighed the risks of what you're doing, and are absolutely sure you want this, then continue reading....

What you have *should* work, I was able to use the same script you have and successfully see the details of the distribution group in the browser. A few things that you can try:

- I doubt this is even remotely related to your problem, but if you're using single quotes, you shouldn't be escaping your path:

  ```
  $command = 'powershell -File "' . dirname(__DIR__) . '\ps\run.ps1"';
  ```
- Make sure you're executing the correct version of PowerShell (32-bit vs. 64-bit). As a sanity check, try running:

  ```
  <?php echo shell_exec('powershell -Command "[intptr]::size"'); ?>
  ```

  If you're on a 64-bit system and see an `8` then you're probably good. If you see a `4`, then you might have issues where your server (e.g. Apache or IIS) or PHP aren't the 64-bit versions. (This is what got me. Once I installed a server stack that was running on 64 bits, everything worked beautifully. Before that, I got errors when trying to load the MSOnline library.)
- Triple-check that the script you have is the script that you're executing (i.e. make sure you aren't working on a copy that is in a different location). One option to debug this is to print out the script itself. Try adding this line to your PHP file:

  ```
  echo '<pre>'
      . htmlentities(file_get_contents(dirname(__DIR__) . '\ps\run.ps1')) 
      . '</pre>';
  ```